# In pipeline job how to build freestyle downstream jobs with their choice parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here i am building multiple freestyle jobs with their choice parameters from one pipeline job.
In my all downstream freestyle job I am using common choice parameters with the values

```
Name:   Branch
Choice: trunk
        branch/2.3
        branch/2.4
```

in my Pipeline also i declared the same parameters in choices

```
Name:   Branch
Choice: trunk
        branch/2.3
        branch/2.4
```

Here is the pipeline code i am using

```
pipeline
{
node any
stage ('JOBS'){ 
                build job: 'testjob1', propagate: false
                build job: 'testjob2', propagate: false
                build job: 'testjob3', propagate: false
                build job: 'testjob4', propagate: false
                build job: 'testjob5', propagate: false
}
}
```

But for me it s building downstream jobs but its taking the default first choice.

Answer (score 0):

The choice parameter always picks up the first choice as default unless you select a different parameter. Since, your freestyle jobs are triggered by an upstream pipeline, you need to explicitly pass your choice for every freestyle job as:

```
build job: 'testjob1', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Branch', value: Branch]], propagate: false
```